# Microsoft Adaptive Card - Column Size

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

Does anyone know what is a proper value to set for column size for adaptive card ? 
Schema (http://adaptivecards.io/explorer/#Column) says

> "auto", "stretch", or a number representing relative width of the
>   column in the column Set (Default:Auto)

but actually I've tried number, percentage, px, pt but none is working.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look to this sample: http://adaptivecards.io/visualizer/?card=/samples/cards/Input%20Form.json

You will see that the format is a basic number:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "0.5",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "ColumnSet",
      "columns": [
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "size": 2,
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Tell us about yourself...",
              "weight": "bolder",
              "size": "large"
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "We just need a few more details to get you booked for the trip of a lifetime!",
              "isSubtle": true,
              "wrap": true
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Don't worry, we'll never share or sell your information.",
              "isSubtle": true,
              "wrap": true,
              "size": "small"
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Your name",
              "wrap": true
            },
            {
              "type": "Input.Text",
              "id": "myName",
              "placeholder": "Last, First"
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Your email",
              "wrap": true
            },
            {
              "type": "Input.Text",
              "id": "myEmail",
              "placeholder": "youremail@example.com",
              "style": "email"
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Phone Number"
            },
            {
              "type": "Input.Text",
              "id": "myTel",
              "placeholder": "xxx.xxx.xxxx",
              "style": "tel"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "size": 1,
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "Image",
              "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Diver_Silhouette%2C_Great_Barrier_Reef.jpg",
              "size": "auto"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Submit"
    }
  ]
}
```

It's working a bit like bootstrap; here your first column will get 2/3 = 2/(2+1) of the total width, and the second one 1 third (1/(2+1)).

You can manipulate the values in the provided tester

Comment: Can you please check the provided tester? There is no information in it!